# What do you call the form $a = bq+r$ in the Euclidean algorithm?

Tags: euclidean-algorithm

Hey guys so I wanted to explain the Extended Euclidean Algorithm, and I wanted to explain the form $a = bq+r$. Is there a name for this form, such as the Divison Algorithm or something? Thanks.

Comment: Lookup [Euclidian division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division#Statement_of_the_theorem).

Comment: It's (Euclidean) division (with remainder), a.k.a. the (integer) division algorithm. Polynomials over a field also have an analogous division algorithm.